# Compute BLEU score of a Pandas DataFrame with valid rows filtered

Tags: python, pandas, bleu, huggingface-evaluate

I have a Pandas DataFrame from an Excel file, which contains text data which need to calculate the BLEU score row-by-row.

```
import evaluate
import pandas as pd
sacrebleu = evaluate.load("sacrebleu")

testset = pd.read_excel(xlsx_filename)
# find out valid rows with all columns are valid
valid_rows = testset['col1'].notna() & testset['col2'].notna() & testset['col3'].notna()

for i in range(len(testset)): # or... for i in range(len(testset.loc[valid_rows, 'col2']))
    score = sacrebleu.compute(predictions=[testset.loc[valid_rows, 'col1'][i], testset.loc[valid_rows, 'col2'][i]], references=[testset.loc[valid_rows, 'col3'][i]])
```

It raises `KeyError: 139`.

The length of `valid_rows` and `testset` are 13700, while the length of `testset.loc[valid_rows, 'col2']` is 12208.

I know loop through for-loop is an anti-pattern, but how can I fit a Series into the `sacrebleu.compute()` function? It accepts only `[string, string], string` as input.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure it's not `sacrebleu.compute(predictions=testset.loc[valid_rows, 'col1'], references=[testset.loc[valid_rows, 'col2'], testset.loc[valid_rows, 'col3']])`? The first argument `predictions` should be a `list` of `str` while the second argument `references` is `list` of `list` of `str`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But how I can apply the data from the data frame filtered rows? Thanks.